# Do shotguns with low accuracy spell failgun?

Tags: borderlands

I just found a shotgun with 3.6 accuracy. (out of 100.0)

Do shotguns treat accuracy differently than other weapons, or should I put this one on my shelf as the 'banger that never banged her... or ... anyone else for that matter...'

I just realized that I have yet a different shotgun with an accuracy of 0.0, which means it should theoretically never hit anything, except for it does all the time. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Accuracy) website seems to be telling me that a shotgun's accuracy (apparently each gun type is somewhat different) measures how much *additional* spread will exist when hip-firing, and that the remaining spread cannot be minimized.

IE: If a shotgun's accuracy is 0.0, then aiming down its sights does nothing for you. Beyond that, all shotguns have the same accuracy, or an improved accuracy (depending on its accuracy stat) for aiming down the sight.