# How does aiming down the sights affect Accuracy?

Tags: borderlands-2

Does firing while aiming down the sights (or through a scope) affect Accuracy of the guns?  Or is it not affected at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do shotguns with low accuracy spell failgun?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85330/do-shotguns-with-low-accuracy-spell-failgun)

Comment: How is this a dupe? This is asking how all weapons are affected by accuracy in Borderlands 2.  Not 1.  The other question pertains to only shotguns and refers to 1.  Though these two games may have the same name, mechanics may be different.

Comment: This is one of those situations where I am using the POSSIBLE or MAY words literally. I'm not sure if it's a dupe, but in theory, one complete answer about how accuracy and ADS works in borderlands would answer both questions, hence, dupe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Accuracy is significantly improved when aiming down the sights in Borderlands 2; a Loading Screen tip even tells you/hints at this. Your bullet spread will be significantly reduced with any weapon, even the individual pellets from shotguns (no that does not make sense but yet it does happen). I'm not sure exactly how much, but it's very noticeable, I'd say it cuts bullet spread (the max distance of any bullet from the center of your aim) in half or so.

This seems to behave differently for different weapons; Sniper Rifles seem to have a much greater benefit from scoping (or perhaps a more significant detriment for firing from the hip). From the hip Snipers have wider spread than SMGs but will have much higher accuracy when zoomed in.

You can easily confirm this by watching your aiming reticle as you zoom in; it will shrink in size considerably as it fades from view, especially noticeable with a low-accuracy weapon (any shotgun).

However note that aiming down the scope will introduce a second effect; random weapon sway. All weapons (particularly Hyperion weapons) sway a bit when aiming. The amount of stability is a [weapon stat](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/84930/11920) not directly related to accuracy. Note that firing a Hyperion weapon decreases weapon sway, firing other weapons increases it. Weapon sway is different from accuracy though; accuracy is the spread of the pellets from the muzzle of the gun; sway actually moves the location of the muzzle (where the speedy kill-people things come out of the gun).

Comment: Remember there are achievements for killing without being scoped in.

Comment: @Taz yeah, I think that's just for Sniper kills from the hip

Comment: Yet stats that increase accuracy seem to reduce weapon sway. I don't think those stats are unrelated, rather the weapon spread is replaced by weapon sway in iron sights mode.